# Elasticsearch query_string query with multiple default fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to avail myself of the feature of a `query_string` query, but I need the query to search by default across a subset of fields (not all, but also not just one). When I try to pass many default fields, the query fails. Any suggestions?

Not specifying a specific field in the query, so I want to search three fields by default:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "some search using advanced operators OR dog",
            "default_field": ["Title", "Description", "DesiredOutcomeDescription"]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create a query on 3 specific fields as above, just use the `fields` parameter.

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "some search using advanced operators OR dog",
            "fields": ["Title", "Description", "DesiredOutcomeDescription"]
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to search by default on those 3 fields without specifying them, you will have to use the `copy_to` parameter when you set up the mapping.  Then set the default field to be the concatenated field.

```
PUT my_index

{
  "settings": {
    "index.query.default_field": "full_name" 
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "first_name": {
          "type": "text",
          "copy_to": "full_name" 
        },
        "last_name": {
          "type": "text",
          "copy_to": "full_name" 
        },
        "full_name": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have used this and don't recommend it because the control over the tokenization can be limiting, as you can only specify one tokenizer for the concatenated field.

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) is the page on copy_to.

Comment: Note that by using `copy_to`, you may miss out on the "field-length norm" factor for determining relevancy. Relying on the `_all` field (deprecated in ES 6.0 btw) suffers from the same effect. More info: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/scoring-theory.html#field-norm